# How to call my custom function inside Google maps event, in angular 2

Tags: angular, google-maps, angular2-template

I am using Angular 2. Using basic google maps, all works fine ,now i want to call my custom function from

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map123,'click' ,(event)=>  {

    let id=123;


    var lat=event.latLng.lat();
    var lng=event.latLng.lng();


    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position:  new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(lat),parseFloat(lng)),
    map: map123
  });
   this.serverinteraction(this.id_actual,this.lat_actual,this.lng_actual);
    });

 My custom function is in same typescript file:

serverinteraction(id , lat, lng)
        {

        }
```

Error: _this.serverinteraction is not a function.

How Can i call my custom function inside that event.

Comment: Try this : 

`google.maps.event.addListener(map123,'click' ,(event)=>  {
   ...
    }.bind(this));`

Comment: I got error msg--> cannot find name 'bind'.did you mean static member 'component.bind'. How resolve this.

Comment: do you have code snippet / jsbin / anything where we can check the code ?

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
var that = this;
google.maps.event.addListener(map123,'click' ,(event)=>  
{
    let id=123;

    var lat=event.latLng.lat();
    var lng=event.latLng.lng();
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position:  new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(lat),parseFloat(lng)),
        map: map123
   });

   that.serverinteraction(this.id_actual,this.lat_actual,this.lng_actual);
});
```